# AngularJS radio buttons not checked on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularJS controller that creates a scope with a list of items and has a property for the selected item.  During initialization I create the list and set the selectedItem property to the second item in the list.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {id: 1, name: "Item 1"},
    {id: 2, name: "Item 2"},
    {id: 3, name: "Item 3"}
    ];

  $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[1];
});
```

The view is a list with a checkbox for each item.

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selectedItem" ng-value="{{item}}" ng-checked="$parent.selectedItem==item">
        {{item.name}}
      </label>
    </div>
    Selected Value: {{selectedItem}}
    <div>
      <button ng-click="selectedItem=items[2]">Select 3</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Everything is working correctly except that the second radio button isn't displaying as checked when the view loads.  Selecting a radio button changes the selectedItem as expected.  I also added a button to demonstrate that I can set the selectedItem to the third item and the radio buttons will update accordingly.

Here is a plunker that demonstrates the issue.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1TbpHgFm5kpa9k3OJtbI?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your html template for the ng-value attribute, it should be

```
      <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selectedItem" ng-value="item">
        {{item.name}}
      </label>
```

Comment: Well duh, I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks!